# When building bitcoind, I receive error "headers.h:36:20: fatal error: db_cxx.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: bitcoind

When building bitcoind on LinuxCoin (Debian based), I receive this error

> "headers.h:36:20: fatal error: db_cxx.h: No such file or directory"

following the instructions at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.txt

I believe the error is caused by the package "libdb4.8++-dev" being non-existant for the distro, as when attempting to "apt-get install" that, I get:

> Package libdb4.8++-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'libdb4.8++-dev' has no installation candidate

NOTE: libdb4.8-dev and all other dependencies are already installed.

It's probably a silly mistake on my part but any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `db_cxx.h` file anywhere? You can check with `locate`.

Comment: No. I used to have the db-5.1.8 version but I removed that as the readme said I needed 4.8.

Comment: If you don't have libdb-devel installed, it won't compile. You can use 5.1.8, just realize your files won't be compatible with builds made with earlier versions.

Comment: Yeah. I've redownloaded and compiled 5.1.8 now and that's all okay but I'm getting the same error. Not sure how to tweak this makefile to include the db5.1.8 directories

Comment: The makefile I am using is: http://pastebin.com/wGpPNjEb. My db-5.1.8 directories are located at /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.5.1/

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - just a small correction - I found the package is called libdb-dev

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `-I <directory>` to the end of the `CXX=g++` line in the `Makefile`. The directory should be the one that contains the `db_cxx.h` file from your BerkeleyDB installation. So, change:

```
CXX=g++
```

to

```
CXX=g++ -I /usr/local/BerkeleyDB.5.1
```

You may need a `/include` or something like that on the end of that. It depends exactly which directory holds the `db_cxx.h` file.

Comment: Worked a treat with Berkeley 5.1.8, thanks.

Comment: Yup thanks, works a treat with Berkeley 5.1.8

Answer (score 20):

I did the following command on Ubuntu and it worked.

```
sudo apt-get install libdb++-dev
```

Comment: brew install berkeley-db on Mac OS X

Answer (score 5):

I think you can install the libdb4.8++-dev package if you add the stable debian repo in your sources.list.

I did it on my system (debian sid), and now I can proceed to the installation.  I haven't tested the full bitcoind compilation yet, though.

Comment: libdb5.1++-dev also works, for those who would rather install later versions of packages. +1 thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it compiles nice with later versions but be carefull and do not mix up db*-dev and db*++-dev.
Here you have to install the "++" version

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing ,db*++-dev instead of db*-dev

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

sudo apt-get install libdb5.3++-dev

The latest stable package, I used this on the new Bitcoin-Qt 8.3 patch from GIT and it compiled flawlessly, for any files that had that as an include.

Note:

If you are using gcc / g++ version 4.8 and you were looking for libdb4.8++-dev, there is a reason why you couldn't find an installation candidate.

Don't confuse the libdb5.3++-dev package with the version of the gcc / g++ compiler and linker, they're not part of the gcc / g++ but an add-on development library regardless of what version of the compiler you use.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building under [homebrew](https://brew.sh) on MacOS, install the requisite header files via

```
brew install berkeley-db
```